# Play 2 configuration file : Reading a list of string variable

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I am trying to read this variable from my Play 2 configuration file :

```
email.bcc = ["name0@domain.com", "name1@domain.com", "name2@domain.com"]
```

Then i try to read it through this line :

```
private val bcc = Play.application.configuration.getStringList("email.bcc")
```

The problem is that i need a type List[String] for bcc and i get a Option[java.util.List[String]]

My question is : How to read a list of string to a List[String] and not this strange "java" type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val myList: List[String] = bbc map (_.asScala.toList) getOrElse Nil
```